# matplotlib xticks misplaced after using ax.set_xlim()

Tags: matplotlib

When I set xlim with ax.set_xlim() my xtick labels are all shifted by one space to the left.

```
fig,axes=plt.subplots(2,1,sharey=True)
x=list(range(0,9))
y=list(range(1,10))
df=pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':y})
ax1=df.plot('x','y',ax=axes[0])
xticklabels=x
ax1.set_xticklabels(x)
```

[image: as expected]

after I add this line to the code

```
ax1.set_xlim(-0.2,8.2)
```

xticks are wrongly placed:

[image: unexpected shif to the left]

Comment: xtick labels wrongly placed I meant

Answer (score 2):

While you set the ticklabels to be the elements of a list, you do not specify the actual tick positions. So you leave it to the automatic `AutoLocator` to place the tick positions, but then set some custom labels to those ticks. 
This will in general not give reasonable results.

As a rule of thumb: If you fix the labels, you need to fix the positions as well.

```
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot seems obvious now